# Is there a way to change 'char (*)[10]' to 'char *'?

Tags: arrays, c, char, warnings

I am attempting to program a calendar system in C, but I constantly receive this same error:

```c
main.c:26:49: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
     'char (*)[10]' [-Wformat]
```

My code is

```c
char months[12][10] = {
                         "January",
                         "February",
                         "March",
                         "April",
                         "May",
                         "June",
                         "July",
                         "August",
                         "September",
                         "October",
                         "November",
                         "December"
                     };
```

for declaring "months", and

```c
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    printf("string = %s \t address = %u\n", months + i, (unsigned int)months + i);
}
```

for printing. I have tried replacing months with `*months`, `**months`, and `(*char)months`, and none have worked. I checked multiple questions on here, but one involved `scanf` which I am not using. Even so, I attempted the answers which did not work for me. Another one involved functions and the answers were to append `**` to the beginning of the args. That also did not work for me. I understand that my issue is likely simple, however, I am unable to find a solution. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What you seem to want is a single element of the `months` array, which (if you know anything about arrays) would be e.g. `months[i]`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have been programming in Python for a while, and so I should have seen the mistake. However, I was unsure if C had special syntax, so I did not think that the example I was given was simply using strange syntax. Thank you very much for pointing that out to me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
printf("string = %s \t address = %u\n", months[i], (unsigned int)&months[i]);
```

You would have to change `%u` to get rid of another warning.